# Trying to run an application on linux that can be accessed remotely

Tags: network-shares, remote, remote-access, remote-control

I am not the best when it comes to explaining my confusing goals so hopefully I make sense.

What I am trying to do is:

Trying to run an application on a server that can be accessed remotely but different people.

The program is one a friend made and it works great on windows. Its free but you have to assign users to it each time someone wants to use it with their own profile.

How can I get this program to be accessed remotely, and it allow different users to use it when they access the server. If it has to be one user, that is fine but would multiple people be able to use it at the same time without effecting each others work?

Hope this made sense.

Program, accessible by multiple, remotely, if I can get it to work on linux, would be great but havent tried it. Works on windows great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, please read [how to ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

For a start: a Windows binary won't run on Linux unless you install Wine (a Windows emulator for Linux). And yet if you have Wine there is a chance that specific application won't work.

Then comes the remote access question. The remote access is solved at operating system level. Both Linux and Windows have their solutions for accessing them remotely. And using the installed software as if you were in front of that computer. Then you will be able to access this program remotely if you have remote access to that computer.

You mentioned something about multiple people using the same application too. That depends on the application. Both Windows and Linux applications are expected to work without problems with multiple users running each one instance. But it utterly depends on the application.

Finally, you weren't clear about the nature of this application. Some software is programmed to work as a server providing their own remote access. But I guess it isn't the case of this application.